# What does “the most widely translated 20th-century” mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning

> Writing to the woman who would become his third wife, Hermann Hesse
>   complained: “Life for me now holds almost no pleasures any more, in
>   fact I am living in Hell.” The event that had reduced Hesse to this
>   state of near-despair was that his wife-to-be Ninon Dolbin had moved
>   some of his books without his permission. For him this was an
>   intolerable disruption of the orderly existence he believed essential
>   to a writer who had detached himself from the world. His independence
>   required that he hold all of humankind, and even his closest
>   companion, at a rigorously policed distance. Accordingly, although the
>   two of them lived under the same roof, he communicated with Ninon
>   mainly in writing. As his latest biographer, Gunnar Decker, relates:
>   Their day-to-day communication with one another was conducted by
>   “house letters”, like in a Trappist monastery, where one has to stay
>   silent most of the time and jot down essential communications to one’s
>   fellow monks on pieces of paper. This was the way Hesse managed to
>   tolerate the presence of another person in his vicinity; he had to be
>   sure he wouldn’t suddenly be spoken to. “How was it,” Decker asks,
>   “that Hesse believed himself to be ‘living in Hell’…when he had a
>   female friend who loved him more unreservedly than any before her, and
>   who placed herself entirely at the service of his needs?” As he
>   comments: “His note sounds positively hysterical.” It is a reasonable
>   judgement. Decker is a scrupulous biographer with an unrivalled
>   knowledge of his subject, and this is undoubtedly the definitive
>   account of Hesse’s life and work. It is less clear what Decker finds
>   of intrinsic interest or value in his subject. The most striking fact
>   about Hesse is how he was embraced by the counterculture in the early
>   Sixties – a development that secured him a posthumous reputation as an
>   exponent of the hippie “drop out” philosophy and made him **the most
>   widely translated 20th-century** German author.

- what is the use of word “translated” here? Can you paraphrase the highlighted part please?

Comment: The adjective "translated" refers to "author". The adjective "20th-century" also refers to "author".

Comment: Further to CowperKettle's point, it is common to say what century an author was writing in, especially when the author's life didn't span more than one century.   Hesse was a 20th century author. And it is common to refer to the author as "translated" when we mean the author's works.  *Jack London is widely translated.*  There, "widely" means "into many languages".

Answer (score 4):

Hermann Hesse is a German author, i.e., he writes his books in the German language. The use of the word "translated" simply refers to the process of rewriting his books in a different language.

MW [gives](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate) the following meaning for "translate"

> to turn into one's own or another language

"the most widely translated 20th-century" means that Hesse was the 20th century author whose works were translated the most in different languages.

Comment: He's a 20th century author.  Translations done in 2005 or 2017 might have put him in first place; the phrase doesn't indicate when the translations were made.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo nice catch. Answer updated accordingly.